# How to select a p tag having a input tag with a class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<pre><p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="sbtn" /></p></pre>
```

I want to add a class to the p tag that only have the input tag with input having  a class sbtn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.has` to select the `p`

```
$('p').has('input.sbtn');
```

Use like this to add the class

```
$('p').has('input.sbtn').addClass('newClass');
```

It'll add class `newClass` to `p`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/62/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method or the [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method. Like:

```
var myP = $('.sbtn').parent();

// or

var myP = $('.sbtn').closest('p');
```

The first gives you the direct parent, the second travels up in the DOM tree untill it finds the first ancestor that matches that tag.

Then just to:

```
myP.addClass('new_class');
```

If you want a oneliner:

```
$('.sbtn').parent().addClass('new_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/). Try this:

```
$('.sbtn').parent().addClass('testClass');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/u8yajcoq/)**